# How to map xml attribute with wso2 data mapper?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 data-mapper to map input schema with output schema. problem here is we are unable to map with xml attributes(either it can be in input schema or output schema)

We are able to map with element based xml but unable to map with attribute values

Below link will show you the input schema and output schema
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dmupfl71Ww_mLQB0gRL1RnmaebrUnzwh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Vikash, could you tell me what version of the EI tooling are you using and what are the input and output XML's? I tried and was able to map an xml element to an attribute so I could not reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for replying! 
We have used WSO2EI 6.4.0 and for data mapping eclipse developer studio Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried mapping xml elements to attributes on both Windows and Mac and both seem to work fine. I would advise to start with a small version of your xml tree and expand to see what the problem could be. One difference that stands out: I put sample data in my XML which does not seem to be the case in your example (since it says 'NULL' everywhere).
[image: mapping to attribute]

XML input:

```
<test>
<owner>theowner</owner>
<status>working</status>
</test>
```

XML output:

```
<test>
<Users owner="me" status="working" />
</test>
```